# How to create a file from render html sails js

Tags: node.js, sails.js, ejs

Trying to make a file that render into ejs how can i do this

```
let makeFile = res.view('file.ejs',{result:result});

fs.writeFile(sails.config.myconf.path+'file.xml', makeFile, function (err, result) {
    if(err){
        console.log(err)
        return
    }
});
```

Tried this way getting undefined always can any one please understand why this is causing issue thanks a ton in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`res.view` is really meant to come at the end of your method. It facilitates a return sent by the `res` object, and I don't think it returns anything useful.

What you want is likely `res.render` - you can use that to get (and then work with) the output html as a string.

```
res.render('file.ejs', {result: result}, function(err, renderedHtml) {
    if (err) { /* handle the error */ }

    // renderedHtml should be the html output from your template
    // use it to write a new file, or whatever is required
    console.log(renderedHtml);

    return res.send({fileCreated: true});
});
```